# show the user's input names in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I make a program in which user enter the 3 names and i'll show the names in alphabatical order.
For example, if the user entered 
    “Charlie,” “Leslie,” and “Andy,” 
the program would display:
    Andy, Charlie, Leslie......

but my output is:

```
Enter a name: charlie

Enter a name: leslie

Enter a name: andy

andy leslie charlie
```

again another output:

```
Enter a name: abc

Enter a name: def

Enter a name: ghi

ghi def abc
```

my output always show third enter name in first order and then second and then first it does't matter what i've write it always show names in this order....
please help me.thanku

```
const int size = 10;
    char name1[size];
    char name2[size];
    char name3[size];

    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin.getline(name1, size);
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin.getline(name2, size);
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin.getline(name3, size);


    if ("name1" > "name2" && "name1" > "name3")
    {
        cout << name1 << " ";
        if ("name2" > "name3")
        {
            cout << name2 << " " << name3 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << name3 << " " << name2 << endl;
        }
    }
    else if ("name2" > "name1" && "name2" > "name3")
    {
        cout << name2 << " ";
        if ("name1" > "name3")
        {
            cout << name1 << " " << name3 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << name3 << " " << name1 << endl;
        }
    }
    else if ("name3" > "name1" && "name3" > "name2")
    {
        cout << name3 << " ";
        if ("name1" > "name2")
        {
            cout << name1 << " " << name2 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << name2 << " " << name1 << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "nothing happened....." << endl;
    }
```

Comment: You want `strcmp()`.

Comment: By putting `name1` in quotes you are making it into a literal word and you are not using it as a program variable.

Comment: What if my name happens to be longer than 9 characters?

Comment: You are writing C++ code, and you are using I/O streams. So why aren't you using `std::string`? This would handle the comparison problems for you, and also prevent the issue of someone who has the name Giovanetta.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, you cannot compare strings using the > and < operators. Look für the string-functions in the runtime library. From these, you want the string compare function strcmp(). Here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with a full example at the end.